# How to get definition of partition function programmatically?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, dmv

I have tables partitioned by date with various frequency space (multi-years, years, quarters, months etc.)

`sys.partition_functions` gives name and function_id.

Is there a way to query the actual definition of a function?

I'd like to join it to a partition size/rowcount view from `sys.partitions` so that when looking at space and rowcount it's immediately obvious for what time period the data is - as opposed to having a partition_number and looking up by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return the partition boundaries for each partitioned table/view/index along with the row count of each partition.

Retrieving detailed space information can be expensive if you have many objects /partitions so I generally leave that code commented-out unless I need the info.

```
SELECT
      CONCAT(QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id)), N'.', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id))) AS ObjectName 
    , i.name AS IndexName
    , p.index_id AS IndexID 
    , ds.name AS PartitionScheme 
    , p.partition_number AS PartitionNumber 
    , fg.name AS FileGroupName 
    , prv_left.value AS LowerBoundaryValue 
    , prv_right.value AS UpperBoundaryValue 
    , CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 1 THEN 'RIGHT' ELSE 'LEFT' END AS PartitionFunctionRange 
    , p.rows AS Rows
--  , pst.used_page_count AS UsedPages,
--  , pst.used_page_count * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
--  , pst.reserved_page_count as ReservedPages,
--  , pst.reserved_page_count * 8 as ReservedSpaceKB
FROM
    sys.partitions AS p 
    --INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS pst ON p.partition_id = pst.partition_id
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS ps ON ps.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions AS pf ON pf.function_id = ps.function_id
    INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds2 ON dds2.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id AND dds2.destination_id = p.partition_number
    INNER JOIN sys.filegroups AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = dds2.data_space_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv_left ON ps.function_id = prv_left.function_id AND prv_left.boundary_id = p.partition_number - 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv_right ON ps.function_id = prv_right.function_id AND prv_right.boundary_id = p.partition_number
ORDER BY
      ObjectName
    , IndexID
    , p.partition_number;
```